# to_csv is too slow exporting to sharedrive through VPN

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv, vpn

hope you're doing good.

I have a python script that takes some csv files, does some basic transformation and outputs a 65mb CSV file. If I save that file to my local disk, the whole process takes 20 seconds. But when working from home I connect to the company's sharedrive through the company's VPN and it takes 8 minutes. I ran the code by chunks and it is the to_csv that is taking so long when creating the CSV file directly to the sharedrive folder.

It could just the a slow VPN connection, but when I manually copy the file from local drive to sharedrive it takes less than a minute at 2mb/s. So its not just a slow VPN connection.

I tried outputting the file with to_csv to my local drive and then using shutil.copy2 to copy it to the sharedrive - it took 25 seconds. How can shutil.copy2 take 25 seconds and pandas.to_csv take 8 minutes? I'm really confused here.

The file had a datetime64 column. I change it to string and it made no difference on the 8 minute runtime. All other columns are string, object, or float.

I also tried to_parquet directly to the sharedrive folder - took 10 seconds for a 2mb file.

Further details: when working in office I have to use a different PC and I use Pycharm installed directly on the sharedrive (Python also installed on the sharedrive, in-office pc is not allowed to have anything installed in it). When running it from there it takes about 1 or 2 minutes. When working from home I have VSCode and Miniconda installed on local disk and connect to sharedrive through VPN.

I really appreciate any input! Thanks everyone

Comment: It sounds like the manual copy is somehow able to do compression, which isn't available when the file is being written incrementally.

Comment: I don't know what's going on but you could use a profiler to gain additional insights into the processing and share your findings.

Answer (score 0):

I can't promise this will work for you, but I've had similar problems and was able to improve performance by writing to a string first, then encoding it and writing it in one step. Let me know if this helps. Naturally, be sure to point `outfile` to your shared drive for testing.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
import timeit

nums = np.random.normal(size=(5000,500))
df_orig = pd.DataFrame(nums)


def orig(df,fname):
    df.to_csv(fname)


def withsio(df,fname):
    with StringIO() as sio:
        df.to_csv(sio)
        sio.seek(0)
        with open(fname, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(sio.getvalue().encode())


print(timeit.timeit('orig(df_orig,\'outfile\')',globals=globals(),number=5))
print(timeit.timeit('withsio(df_orig,\'outfile\')',globals=globals(),number=5))
```